# undefined variable res while trying to login using angular / spring security

Tags: angular, typescript, jwt

i'm trying to authenticate using angular / spring security

my backend work perfectly .

the problem is with this function which is reponsible for login :

```
  onFormSubmit(authBody: authBody ) {

    this.authService.login(authBody)
      .subscribe(res => {
        console.log(res);
        if (res.token) {
          localStorage.setItem('token', res.token);
          this.router.navigate(["/menu"]);
        }
      }, (err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }
```

console.log(res) return :
{username=med, token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJtZWQiLCJyb2xlcyI6W10sImlhdCI6MTYzOTA2NzgzOSwiZXhwIjoxNjM5MDcxNDM5fQ.a-DzNNeVRZ6XUPwYnzAk_P_0yFQO5GXwvBds_7RvGs8}

i try to get the token from this object , but when testing with if(res.token) it return undefined .

this my authentification method service :

```
login(authBody: authBody): Observable<any> {
    console.log(authBody.username);
    return this.http.post(apiUrl + this.aPILogin, authBody ,{responseType: 'text'})
      .pipe(
        tap(_ => this.isLoggedIn = true),
        catchError(this.handleError('login', []))
      );
  }
```

any suggestion pleaaase ?

Thank youuuu

Comment: What do you get if yo run "typeof res"? Can you check it it is a string or an object or anything else? Try to put your responseType as "application/json"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you defined the `responseType` as text, your getting a `string` from the observable, not an `object`.

For this to work as you expect you have to do two things:

1.- Return a proper JSON from the server. (Can't help you with that cause I've never used Spring).

2.- Remove the responseType( its default value is json) so the response body gets parsed into an object.

cheers